# Android: How to create expandable item in listview (!Not expanded listview)?

Tags: java, android, listview

How to create expandable item in ListView (Kitkat Alarm List item)?

[image]

Comment: You created an ExpandableListView ?

Comment: Yeah... that is an ExpandableListView. Easiest way to go about it.